# Returning 204 No Content from Actix Web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have a function, with the signature:

```
async fn index(bearer_control: web::Json<BearerControl>) -> Result<String> {
```

It is used an a web server:

```
HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route("/", web::post().to(index)))
    .bind_openssl("127.0.0.1:1618", builder)?
    .run()
    .await
```

I want to return a 204 No Content.

I've tried returning an empty string, but that is still a 200 OK.

What sort of function return type do I need from `index()` and how do I attach a function with a different return type to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actix-web expects your handlers to return something that can be converted to an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpResponse.html), which of course includes `HttpResponse` itself:

```
async fn index(bearer_control: web::Json<BearerControl>) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::new (StatusCode::NO_CONTENT)
}
```